# What would be a good journal to publish an animal population density estimate using acoustic data?

Tags: marine-species, density-estimation, passive, publication

I have recently submitted a manuscript estimating density of fin whales using passive acoustic data to the Journal of the Acoustical Society of America. This manuscript is largely method based as it provides a framework for estimating cetacean density from a mobile recording platform, a deep-water ocean glider. Because of the technical/methodological aspects of this study, I think JASA was an appropriate journal.

But, it got me thinking that if the study had instead been focused on the actual density estimate, that just *happened* to use passive acoustic data to estimate the density, what would be a more appropriate journal? Or would JASA be good?

Comment: This is an interesting question because my first instinct was to say we don’t need to publish every single abundance estimate… but in fact managers are encouraged to make decisions based on publicly available information, and results published in peer reviewed journals are more defensible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the goal of the study was to provide an accurate abundance estimate and the passive acoustic monitoring was just the established tool, JASA would not be the journal to reach your audience.  Much more appropriate to go for something like Marine Mammal Science if the focus is on the fin whales, or an ecological journal, such as Applied Ecology, if there are clear management implications.

Answer (score 9):

One option for marine species is [Fishery Bulletin](https://spo.nmfs.noaa.gov/fb.htm)

I second [Journal of Applied Ecology](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/13652664) (noted above), [Biological Conservation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/biological-conservation/about/aims-and-scope) (for species of concern, such as fin whales), or if you were feeling patient, you could consider [Journal of Cetacean Research & Management](https://journal.iwc.int/index.php/jcrm) (IWC).

For methodological journals, another suggestion is [Environmental and Ecological Statistics](https://www.springer.com/journal/10651) or [Methods in Ecology and Evolution](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/2041210X)

Answer (score 4):

I've definitely seen those  kinds of papers in Methods in Ecology & Evolution, but it's typically more a description of the statistical method with a case study rather than the implications of the case study per se (e.g., see below).

Stevenson, B. C., van Dam‐Bates, P., Young, C. K., & Measey, J. (2021). A spatial capture–recapture model to estimate call rate and population density from passive acoustic surveys. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 12(3), 432-442.

Doser, J. W., Finley, A. O., Weed, A. S., & Zipkin, E. F. (2021). Integrating automated acoustic vocalization data and point count surveys for estimation of bird abundance. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 12(6), 1040-1049.

Wright, W. J., Irvine, K. M., Almberg, E. S., & Litt, A. R. (2020). Modelling misclassification in multi‐species acoustic data when estimating occupancy and relative activity. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 11(1), 71-81.

Chambert, T., Waddle, J. H., Miller, D. A., Walls, S. C., & Nichols, J. D. (2018). A new framework for analysing automated acoustic species detection data: Occupancy estimation and optimization of recordings post‐processing. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 9(3), 560-570.

However, if you are less so describing the method and more so placing emphasis on what the density estimation shows/implications of the results, I agree with Journal of Applied Ecology!

Answer (score 4):

Frontiers in Marine Science is another good one.